# MongoDB connection when node server starts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to establish a connection with the MongoDB server, I have the following code declared in the separate file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fs');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function dbError(){
    console.log('Connection Error');
});

db.once('connected', function dbConnected(){
    console.log('Connected to the database');
});

db.on('disconnected', function dbDisconnected(){
    console.log('Database disconnected');
});

process.on('SIGINT', function closeConnection(){
    mongoose.connection.close(function(){
        console.log('Server is down, closing the connection');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

I have my main server code as following

```
var express = require('express'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8443;

var app = express();
//other middlewares
.......

app.listen(port, function () {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    console.log('Sample service running on %s:%d', this.address().address, this.address().port);
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
});
```

I am not sure how to import the connection established in the mongoose file and use it in my main server. So whenever the server starts I want it to connect to MongoDB server first.

Comment: Have you tried using module.exports?

Answer (score 0):

Just import your mongoose connection file at the top of your server file:

```
require('path/to/file');
```

...and then your mongoose models will just use that connection automatically.

Comment: so i don't need to export anything from my mongoose file

Comment: No you don't need to export anything

Answer (score 0):

Export the contents.

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fs');
var db = mongoose.connection;

exports.connect = function(){

  db.on('error', function dbError(){
      console.log('Connection Error');
  });
  db.once('connected', function dbConnected(){
    console.log('Connected to the database');
  });

  db.on('disconnected', function dbDisconnected(){
    console.log('Database disconnected');
  });

  process.on('SIGINT', function closeConnection(){
    mongoose.connection.close(function(){
        console.log('Server is down, closing the connection');
        process.exit(0);
    });
  });
}
```

Import your file then call the function.

```
var foo = require("/path/to/file");

foo.connect();
```

Comment: I did it without using the exports and was able to get it working. But i like your way of invoking connect in the main file.